# Java - How do I check if my machine makes a connection to a given URL

Tags: java, networking, automation, client-server

this is my first question here. I would like to know a way by which I can detect if my machine has made connection to a given URL.

Suppose one of my windows application makes a connection to www.abc.com. I want to detect from my java application(different from the one that made the URL connection) if the connection is made by my machine. I am designing an automation that detects any outgoing connections from my machine

Is this possible using JAVA? or any other method that I can use to get this. Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of firewall in java?

Comment: Basically, I have an automation that checks if another application(that I launch and is not under my control after that) makes an HTTP connection to a specified URL. If it does, I move forward. Otherwise, I stop my automation. 

How do I get to know when that application makes an HTTP call..

Comment: That's exactly what a firewall would do. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing): "In computing, a firewall is a network security system that monitors and controls the incoming and outgoing network traffic based on predetermined security rules. [...]"

Comment: I'll check into it Alexander and come back if I face any problem. Thanks.